# Place text in the middle of shinydashboard body

Tags: r, shinydashboard

How can you place text exactly in the middle between left and right end of shiny dashboard body at this height?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(5,),
      column(4,
             span(h2(strong("Covid-19 Situation Dashboard"), style = 'font-size:30px;color:#6cbabf;')))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `align = "center"`, as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      #column(5,),
      column(12,
             span(h2(strong("Covid-19 Situation Dashboard"), align = "center", style = 'font-size:30px;color:#6cbabf;')))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it does not seem to be in the center and even if I set left alignment. maybe because of the sidebar space?

Comment: By specifying `column(12,...)`, you can set it to center of page, as there is no sidebar.